# READ json file to create environment variable in Docker Compose ENTRYPOINT

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

My docker container has some inline commands to run on ENTRYPOINT. Command inside entry point uses json file which is mounted already in volumne.

I can also see that file is already mounted on /cfg/config.json inside container.

But I am getting issue while running the container.

Here is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  dtta:
    image: "image_path"
    network_mode: "host"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - FIXED_CONFIG_1=val1
      - FIXED_CONFIG_2=val2
    volumes:
      - /home/${SUDO_USER}/test/ta/cfg:/cfg
    entrypoint: ["for keyval in $$(grep -E '\": [^\\{]' /cfg/config.json | sed -e 's/: /=/' -e \"s/\\(\\,\\)$$//\"); do echo export $$keyval; eval export $$keyval; done && /dtta"]
    depends_on:
      - other_service
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "5mb"
        max-file: "5"
        mode: non-blocking
```

But, I am getting below error in console

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "for keyval in $(grep -E '\": [^\\{]' /cfg/config.json | sed -e 's/: /=/' -e \"s/\\(\\,\\)$//\"); do echo export $keyval; eval export $keyval; done && /dory": stat for keyval in $(grep -E '": [^\{]' /cfg/config.json | sed -e 's/: /=/' -e "s/\(\,\)$//"); do echo export $keyval; eval export $keyval; done && /dtta: no such file or directory: unknown
```

Is there something which I am missing here?

Comment: (Could you restructure the variable list as `KEY=value`, one variable to a line, and give that file to Compose `env_file:`?)

Comment: It would be much better to do this in a separate shell script.

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes and backslash gives problem i think

```
entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "for keyval in $(grep -E '\": [^\\{]' /cfg/config.json | sed -e 's/: /=/' -e \"s/\\(\\,\\)$//\"); do echo export $keyval; eval export $keyval; done && /dtta"]
```

Comment: Great thanks, it works. Although I had to use $$ for variables.